# Limits: $\lim_{x\to0^+}xe^\frac{-1}x$ and $\lim_{x\to0^-}xe^\frac{-1}x$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}xe^\frac{-1}x \text{ and } \lim_{x\to0^-}xe^\frac{-1}x$$

Can anyone help me how to find these limits?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please exhibit at least some attempt at solving the problem yourself? Then we can comment and give some hints. This is not the "society of people who do your homework for you."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set $y=\frac 1x$,

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}xe^\frac{-1}x=\lim_{y\to+\infty}\frac{e^{-y}}y=0$$

set $y=-\frac 1x$, 
$$\lim_{x\to0^-}xe^\frac{-1}x=-\lim_{y\to+\infty}\frac {e^y}y=-\infty$$